# Cannot Delete AWS Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-directory-services, amazon-workdocs

I want to delete an aws directory but when I try, it gives me this error:

[image]

> An Error Has Occurred
>
> Cannot delete the directory because it still has
> authorized applications. **Please deregister the directory before**
> **proceeding.**

As it has said in the error message, I have to **deregister** it to be able to delete it. However, the directory is not even registered! and the 'Deregister' command is grayed out:
[image]

I also went into the 'Applications' section (in the left pane) and found no application.

What's going on here?

Comment: If you think it's not about programming, then where should I post it?

Comment: I recommend to move it to serverfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue seems to be a shortcoming from Amazon. Amazon should have given me a proper error message. Anyway, I noticed that if I go to AWS Directory Service and try to delete the directory, it explains me the root of the issue:

[image]

So I went to AWS WorkDocs Service and deleted it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  I could not delete the Active Directory on my end, either until I saw your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I checked WorkDocs and there were no sites that I could delete. I had to create a new site and then go through the steps of deleting and selecting delete the user directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete an AWS directory by using following steps,

Step 1 -: Get into AWS directory service

Step 2 -: Go to application management

Step 3 -: Identify apps & services bound to ad, marked as enabled

Step 4 -: Go to individual service/app and delete those

Answer (score 0):

It also can happen because there are other dependencies not listed by the error message above, such as SSO pointing out to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

These below steps worked for my issue.

1. Go to Single sign-on (SSO)
2. Dashbord - Setting - Management
3. go to Delete AWS sso config - AwsDelete